# How to restore a SQL Server 7.0 .bak file to SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `.bak` file from SQL Server 7.0 and I want to restore this old `.bak` file to SQL Server 2008 Express. So what should I do?

Comment: The latest version of SQL Server you can use to restore a 7.0 backup directly is SQL 2005. So you could restore the backup to SQL 2005, backup the database, and then restore to SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

According to Technet (see full article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177398(v=sql.105).aspx)) you have three options:

1. Upgrade your **SQL Server 7.0** database by attaching/restoring the database to an instance running **SQL Server 2000** or **SQL Server 2005**, backup your database in SQL Server 2000 or 2005 format and then restore it in SQL Server 2008.
2. Use the SQL Server **Import and Export Wizard** to copy data between multiple instances of SQL Server.
3. Migrate data from a database that was created in SQL Server 7.0 using **bcp utility** (version 7.0 of bcp to export from SQL Server 7.0 and version 10.50 of bcp to import in SQL Serevr 2008).

The first option is probably the easiest and safest.